# Powershell : getting AD groups without members

Tags: powershell

I want to get AD groups with no members like below.  How can I get this?

My desired output:

```
Group Name, Members
Group01 , YES
GRoup02 , NO
```

Here is my script :

```
$groups = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\unused groups\unused.csv"

foreach ($group in $groups) { 


$GroupMembers = Get-ADGroup -Identity $($group.Name) -Properties Members 

if(($GroupMembers.Members).count -eq 0)
{
Write-host "TRUE"

}
else{
Write-host "FALSE"
}


}
```

Comment: If you want to use the `.Count` property, then you need to make sure it is an array by wrapping it in `@()` like `if(@($GroupMembers.Member).count -eq 0)`. Btw. it is `Member`, not `Members`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear if you're looking to export the result to CSV or simply display the object to the console, in case it's the latter just remove the `Export-Csv` part.

```sh
Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\unused groups\unused.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $out = @{ 'Group Name' = $_.Name }
    if((Get-ADGroup $_.Name -Properties Member).Member) {
        $out['Members'] = 'YES'
    }
    else {
        $out['Members'] = 'NO'
    }
    [pscustomobject] $out
} | Export-Csv path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```